# Retrieve images from database through a jQuery AJAX call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, viewbag

Controller to get an image:

```
public class PicturesSmallController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Details(int id)
  {
    PictureSmallManager m = new PictureSmallManager();
    PictureSmall p = m.Load(id);
    ImageFormat imageFormat = ImageHelper.ConvertToImageFormat(p.ContentType);
    return p.Trunk != null ? File(p.Trunk, p.ContentType) : null;
  }
}
```

and a view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var picsSmall = $('#picturesSmall');
  picsSmall.toggle();
  var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "PicsSmall")';
  var ai = {
    id: 69
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(ai),
    success: function (returndata) {
        picsSmall.append($('<img/>', {
          src: returndata,
          alt: 'some text'
        }));
      select.show('slow');
    }
  }
 );
});
</script>
<div id="picturesSmall"></div>
<div id="picturesBig"></div>
```

in result I do not see any picture on the page but I got the same result in FireBug:

```
<div id="picsSmall" style="display: block;">
<img src="�����JFIF��`�`���� ...... �d��:1�g�" alt="some text">
</div>
```

I have two questions:

1. I would like to display image correctly. Could you tell me what is wrong here? I am not good in mvc.
2. I have two the same images the first one is small and the second is big. I would like to show the big image when user click the small. What is the best way to implement it?

If I understand right when picture is loaded to the client side I have to save it in ViewBag. If it's correct, what is the best way to synchronize small and big pictures (should I use array or object on the client side)? Are there any other ways?
Sorry, it looks more complex than I expected.

Comment: Why not write a generic http handler and use it as a source for img? Would be easier and without any unnecessary complications

Comment: src="YourFIle's url here" not the image data itself. See what File() returns : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: yes but there will be link to controller, for example /PicsSmall/Details/69 Sorry for stupid question but I do not know where the image is because it's only request to the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning image bytes from your action. You can't set raw bytes as source, but can use [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as source. You'll need to change format you've returned from your action to be properly formatted string with base64 encoded bytes of the image. Note that some browsers have restrictions on size of the data.

Sample from Wikipedia page:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

Comment: thank you a lot! it's clear and what is the best way in my case to save images on the client side?

Comment: @user1482281, normally if you retrieve images via GET (with url like ".../Details/PicSmall?id=69" and ".../Details/PicLarge?id=69") you would simple set img.src to that URL and all would be fine, since you want use POST you can't do that and may be ok with data URIs. Your second part of question (which you should have asked separately) is pure jQuery/HTML manipulation - handle click and show/hide stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you can convert your object to an Image object (or if you are getting an image object)
you can set the return type of your method to FileContentResult and return a MemoryStream.
Then you set your src to be the path to your controller method.

Controller will have something to the following effect:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public FileContentResult GetImage(int id)
    {
        Image myimage = Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/myimage.jpg"));
        var format = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        string mimeType = "jpeg";

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        myimage.Save(ms, format);

        return File(ms.ToArray(), "images/" + mimeType);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<img src="/MyController/GetImage?id=<%: myImageId %>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

set your image scr as

```
src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsY......
```

and regarding showing thumbnail clickable to open a large image you can use [UI Bloxk Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)